# Vue js issues recalling url from API

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, url

I’m trying to display the store URLs from an API.
In the API are available different URLs and in the output, they are displayed as one single link. How can I display URLs in different lines?

My vue code:

```
<a v-bind:href=“storeUrl”>
{{storeUrl}}
</a>
```

My script:

```
....
computed:{
storeUrl() {
return this.games.store.map(({{url}}) => url).join(‘ ’)
},
}
```

I’m using https://api.rawg.io/api/games API

[This is the current output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJRyt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solves some problems after @chillin's answer.

As I mentioned in the comments, the reason you're not seeing any store urls is that you are iterating over an object that doesn't exist:

> The problem, (as @chillin saw) is that you are iterating through
> `game.store` when you should be iterating through `game.stores` If you
> inspect the `game` object, you'll notice that there is a `stores`
> array within, but not a `store` one.

You should also note that having the urls in anchors on their own will cause them to be squashed into one line. Wrapping the anchors in `<p>` elements solves that problem:

**Before:**

```
<a v-for="store in game.store" :href="store.url" :key="store.ID">{{store.url}}</a>
```

[image: before]

**After:**

```
<p v-for="store in game.stores" :key="store.ID">
    <a :href="store.url">{{store.url}}</a>
</p>
```

[image: after]

Also, I'm not sure if the `stores` array could ever have duplicate IDs, (maybe if multiple versions of the same game are in the same store), but if that ever does happen your code could crash. So it might be a better option to simply use the index of the object as it's key, like so,

```
<p v-for="(store, index) in game.stores" :key="index">
    <a :href="store.url">{{store.url}}</a>
</p>
```

...so as to avoid this potential problem.

[Here's a demo](https://kosvl.csb.app/#/game/4200) and here's the [modified codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/26082020-collaborative-forked-kosvl?file=/src/views/game.vue) (I also removed the computed property `storeUrl`, as it was unused.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated with actual example**

First, don't join them in the computed, and then implement using a v-for, something like this should work.

Basically this is my own take of course, but based on the actual API data, something like this should work, with a loop in a loop, I map out the data just for ease of use, you will end up with something like:

```
[
   {
      key: 'gta-v',
      storeUrls: [
         {
            key: 'steam',
            url: 'http:// ...'
         },
         {
            key: 'riot',
            url: 'http:// ...'
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      key: 'fortnite',
      storeUrls: [
         {
            key: 'steam',
            url: 'http:// ...'
         },
         {
            key: 'riot',
            url: 'http:// ...'
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Using this we can also double down on a v-for in the template, and sort your data by game, and for each game loop through it's storeUrl's for a nice clean list, this also utilises the use of actual keys, rather than index.

```
<template>
   <div class="root">
      <div class="game" v-for="game in games" :key="game.key">
         <h1>{{ game.key }}</h1>
         <a v-for="store in game.storeUrls" :href=“store.url” :key="store.key">
            {{store.url}}
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

export default {
   data() {
      return {
         myData: null
      }
   },

   computed: {
      games() {
         if (!this.myData) return [];
         return this.myData.results.map(game => {
            key: game.slug,
            storeUrls: game.stores.map(store => {
               return {
                  key: store.store.slug,
                  url: store.url_en
               }
            });
         });
      }
   },

   methods: {
      getData() {
         // However you do it, but the base data, with no mapping.
         this.myData = axios.get('...'); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I got error in v-for because a :key is required.  But it seems that this solution works with some elements but not with other.... some of them are still displayed as a single link

Comment: I've updated with the solution for that as well. @chillin (below answer) is right though, it's bad practice to use the index. Mapping the URL's into objects, and adding actual keys would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Vue, so maybe someone else can provide a better answer. But seems right to use `v-for` to loop over your store URLs.

---

Assuming your `gameId` watcher is running and completing successfully, I don't think you need to change anything since `this.game.stores` should already contain an array of objects.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
<a v-for="store in game.stores" :href="store.url" :key="store.store.id">{{ store.url }}</a>
```

I don't know the difference between `store.id` and `store.store.id`, but I've assumed that `store.store.id` uniquely identifies a store and is okay to be used as the `key`. (You'd have to check the API documentation to see what the IDs represent.)

Comment: I’m new too and generally I don’t know much about coding, so can I ask you how can I change this.games.store into an array of objects? If it can help you I’d share codesandbox link

Comment: @MariannaPascucci, okay, send the link. I basically need to see how exactly you're currently getting store URLs into `this.games.store`.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/26082020-collaborative-forked-7f5er?file=/src/views/game.vue right now something is not working D:

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/26082020-collaborative-forked-7f5er?file=/src/views/game.vue Reposting the link to be sure changes were saved

Comment: The problem, (as @chillin saw) is that you are iterating through `game.store` when you should be iterating through `game.stores` If you inspect the `game` object, you'll notice that there is a `stores` array within, but not a `store` one.